# Program compiling on Visual Studio 2010 but not on VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, stl

I'm working on a soft which was written in C++ with VS 2010 a few years ago and when I want to compile it now it shows me errors. I precise that it still works if you use VS 2010 but I only have 2015 at my work.

I made a simple code to show you the error, it involves a template class tab1D that inherits from vector and redefines operators such as "()".

Here is the simplified code:

simple main :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "memory_tab.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    tab1D<int> t (2);
    cout << "Initialization works fine" << endl;
    cout << t[1] << endl;
    cout << "Bracket operator works fine" << endl;
    cout << t(1) << endl; // this line calls parenthesis operator which is overwritten in memory_tab.h. It does not compile.
    cout << "Error C3867 & C2100" << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

memory_tab.h :

```
//includes and stuff    
template <class T>
class tab1D : public vector<T>
{
public:
//  //Constructors
//  /*!
//   * \brief Default constructor (set nbElem and tailleMem to 0)
//   */
    tab1D() : vector<T>() {};
    tab1D(int _nbElem) : vector<T>(_nbElem) {}; // set all elements to 0

//  //Operators
    T& operator() (unsigned val); 
    T& operator() (unsigned val) const;

};

template <class T> T& tab1D<T>::operator() (unsigned val)
{
    return *(_Myfirst + val);
}

template <class T> T& tab1D<T>::operator() (unsigned val) const
{
    return *(_Myfirst + val);
}
```

When I try to compile it, it shows me errors [C3867](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/b0x1aatf.aspx) et [C2100](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bzf3eha6.aspx) at the return of the operator (). But these do not seems to have any reason to pop at this moment : _Myfirst is an attribute of the vector class  and it should be ok.

How can I fix this (the real file is over 3000 lines long with 600 errors, always C3867 and C2100), can I work in some sort of compatibility mode between VS 2015 and VS 2010 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Having some trouble wrapping my head around the compiler messages myself. What happens to your [mcve] when you strip out the conditional compilation? Returning a non-`const` reference from a `const` method shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Mr Burr looks to have picked off the problem in the meantime, but you will still have a problem with the return type in the `const` version of `operator()`

Comment: Yep, I changed that making a copy of the value i want to return efore returning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is relying on the internal implementation details of the `std::vector` class, namely the `_Myfirst` member.

The implementation of `std::vector` changed between VS2010 and VS2015 such that `_Myfirst` was a simple pointer in VS2010 but is a member function that returns a reference to a pointer in VS2015.

You should write your code so that the `tab1D` class uses only the public, non-internal interface to `std::vector` (you might already be there with the code in the `APP_LINUX` blocks).

Comment: Indeed, either using the linux version, or adding parenthesis to _Myfirst removes the errors, thank you !

Comment: Best to take the advice to not use internal library implementation details. That stuff can change out from under you without a moment's notice.

Comment: Yep I did not write that code, will change it to fit the standart though